# warning: passing argument 1 of ‘strcmp’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]

Tags: c, string

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main ()
{
    int i, containizioa,lenstringa;
    char stringa[20], stringhemin3[20], strG[30];
    containizioa = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < 7; i++)
    {
        printf("Inserisci una stringa\n");
        scanf("%s", stringa);
        if (strcmp(stringa[0], "a"))
        {
            containizioa++;
        }
        lenstringa = strlen(stringa);
        if (lenstringa <= 3)
        {
           strcat(stringhemin3, " ");
           strcat(stringhemin3, stringa);
        }
        if (strcmp(stringa[0], "g"))
        {
            strcat(strG, "_");
            strcat(strG, stringa);
        }
        
    }
    printf("Le stringhe di lunghezza inferiore o uguale a 3 sono: %s\n",stringhemin3);
    printf("Il numero di stringhe che iniziano per a è: %d\n", containizioa);
    printf("Le stringhe che iniziano per g sono: %s", strG);
  return 0;
}
```

This is my code, it's supposed to get the first char of the string "stringa" so then i can show all the strings that start with "g" but when I compile this error appears:

```
warning: passing argument 1 of ‘strcmp’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
```

I tried removing the "[0]" but then the code counted all strings with "g" in it, and also tried replacing it with [1] but the same thing happened.

Comment: `strcmp(stringa[0], "a")` is incorrect. This compares *one character* to a string. Do you mean `if (stringa[0] == 'a')`? Note the different quotes used.

Comment: OT: `strcat(stringhemin3, " ");` The buffer `stringhemin3` is uninitialised, making this operation unpredictable. (Same for `strG`.) AND, it seems 7 iterations of max length 3 plus extra SP (ie: 4) might have yielded a string requiring 28+1 bytes... `stringhemin3[20]` isn't big enough, and this will cause _undefined behaviour_.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many issues

1. `stringa[0]` has `char` type and it is an integer. `strcmp` requires pointer to char.
2. `strcmp` compares `C` strings so the whole `stringa` has to be `"g"` (so it will not work for "gamma").

To see if the particular character of string (in this case first) is equal to a specific character simply:

```
if (stringa[0] == 'g'))
```

You do need any functions for that.

---

You can of course use `strcmp` for it if you use compound literals (it is a very weird way ):

```
if (!strcmp((char []){stringa[0],0}, "g"))
```